# How to solve $-\frac{d ^2 u}{d r^2} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{ du}{dr} = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## solve :

## $$-\frac{d ^2 u}{d r^2} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{ du}{dr} = 1$$ in  $0 <r < 1$, $u'(0)=0=u(1)$

My attempt : Im  using  the  theorem of solution by removal of the  first derivative

Here $p= \frac{1}{r}$, $Q=1$

and $z= e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int pdr}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log r}= r^{-1/2}$

Is its  True ?

Now $ Q_1= Q - \frac{1}{2} \frac{dp}{dr} - \frac{1}{4} p^2 = 1+\frac{1}{2r^2}- \frac{1}{4r^2}=1$

Now th given equation trnasforms into  $\frac{d^2v}{ dr^2} + Q_1 v =0$  where $y= vz = vr^{-1}$

$-\frac{d^2v}{ dr^2} + 1 v =0$

so $-D^2 +1 =0$ implies $D= -1 , 1$

Solution $v= c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x} $

Comment: A perhaps simpler approach: if you define $w = \frac{du}{dr}$ then the ODE is just $w' - \frac{1}{r}w = 1$ which you can solve for $w$ by finding the integrating factor. Then its just one more integral to find $u$ from $w$.

Comment: You can check the answer yourself.  Plug it into the equation.  In particular, you have to satisfy the boundary conditions $u'(0)=0=u(1)$.

Comment: I would start with defining $w(r)=u(r)+\frac{r^2}{4}$.  This would give $\frac{d^2w}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dw}{dr}=0,$ which is easy to solve.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool  when $r=0$, it will not defined  because $ \frac{1}{0}$  doesnot exist

Comment: @Winther i got $w= r \log r$ after that  what i have to do ?

Comment: What is your point?  The DE $y'(x)=\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ is also not defined when $x=0$, but it has a perfectly nice solution $y(x)=C e^{\frac{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{2}}$.

Comment: Use that $w = \frac{du}{dr} = r\log(r)$. So integrate one more time.

Comment: okss @Winther i got $ u= \frac{1}{2}r^2 \log r- \frac{1}{4} r^2 + c$

Comment: Well you have changed the ODE now so you will have to do it again, but the same procedure works. In the end you fix the constant with the boundary condition and then you can check that what you get indeed satisfy the ODE by plugging it in.

Comment: but $ u'(r)=  r \log r +r^2 \frac{1}{2r} - 2r$  it will not defined at $r=0$

Comment: You are to solve it on $(0,1)$ with given BC at $0$ and $1$. The limit $r\to 0^+$ is well defined.

Comment: ohhhs  ohh ya @Winther u r right   okss let me thinks  again

Comment: okss that mean $u(r)= \frac{1-r^2}{4}$  Is its  correct ?? @Winther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would solve this ODE is by the following steps (also changed r & u to x & y respectively): 
$$ -xy''-y'=x $$
This is a non-homogeneous ODE thus y(x)=g(x)+h(x)
such as g(x) satisfies the homogeneous ODE:
$$ -xg''-g'=0 $$
solving for g we get & substituting $$g'=u$$
$$ -xu'=u $$
By using separation of variables:
$$\int \:\frac{du}{u}=\int \:\frac{-dx}{x}$$
$$\ln \left(u\right)=\ln \left(\frac{c_1}{x}\right)$$
$$ g=c_2+c_1\ln \left(x\right)\ $$
Now back to our ODE:
$$ -x(h''(x)-\frac{c_1}{x^2})-h'(x)-\frac{c_1}{x} =x $$
$$ -xh''(x)-h'(x)=x $$
In this case we assume $$ h=Cx^k $$
Thus:
$$ -Ck(k-1)x^{k-1}-Ckx^{k-1}=x $$
By comparing degrees of polynomials:
$$ k=2 $$
Thus: $$ -2C-2C=-4C=1 $$ $$C=-\frac{1}{4} $$
Thus: $$ y(x)=c_2+c_1\ln \left(x\right)\ -\frac{x^2}{4}$$
$$ y(1)=c_2 -\frac{1}{4}$$
$$c_2=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$y'(0)=0$$ when $$c_1=0$$
thus $$ y(x)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{x^2}{4}$$
Sorry if the solution is a bit lengthy;I wanted it to be detailed.

Comment: thanks u so much Sarah

Answer (score 4):

$$-\frac{d ^2 u}{d r^2} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{ du}{dr} = 1$$
Multiply both sides by $-r$:
$$ru'' + u' =- r$$
Rewrite it as this and integrate:
$$(ru')'=-r$$